# Possible to stop availability an in App Store, but keep providing a last update for it?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to **withdraw a lite version** of an app, since the full version became free (and features can be bought trough In-App purchase).

But I want to **provide an update for the current lite version owners** with some message like "Go get the full version for free". But I don't want any newcomers to download the lite version.

What to do now?
Any similar experiences?

Comment: Is the lite-version of App registered to receive push notifications on user's device ?

Comment: I was thinking, if you had push notification system enabled then you can send a notification to lite users about full version and take the app out of app store.

Comment: But can I send push notification to an App that is not "Ready for sale"?

Comment: I think I'll simply change the lite app to just show a sole screen that informs everybody about the changes, maybe include some information about the changes in App description too, then withdraw it from store later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set App's availability to a future date?